# How to get get common elements that are in multiple arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440165/how-to-loop-through-multiple-arrays-to-find-something-common/34440408?noredirect=1#comment56622785_34440408)  previously and had some answers. I thought the answers given were pretty helpful but I've only realized now the answer I chose doesn't necessarily serve its purpose as it doesn't get the elements that are in all the arrays. What happens in the answer I chose CodeiSir is that it breaks when I use it more than once and doesn't give the common elements in the arrays. I have tried using underscore.js but that turned out to be a disaster. This is what I have:

A website containing a slider, several checkboxes and a radio group. The user can slide the slider and adjust the price of the resort he wants. He can tick what activities he wants to do via some checkboxes and the ratings via the radio group. Each element (i.e. slider, checkboxes, radio group) returns an array. In the element of the array contains names of the resorts. So e.g. if the user selects several options, this is what the array may contain:

```
priceArray = ["resortC", "resortA"];
ratingArray = ["resortC"];
activitiesArray = ["resortB", "resortC"];
destinationArray = [null];
```

As you can see, the common resort amongst all the arrays is resortC (ignore the null array). I need something that will get me the the string that is contained in all the arrays. The arrays can also change dynamically. E.g. 2 arrays may be null or even all of them or even none of them.

Comment: And did you try any of the other answers in the question you asked previously? I ask because I posted an answer there that accepts any number of arrays, and should do what you're now asking here

Comment: Oh I must've forgot to try that one when I tried all the answers. That actually works! Thank you very much. Can you explain the part how you are passing arrays into the function when you have no explicitly wrote that the function should take in arguments. E.g. `function common(){..}` but you call the function with arugments: `var result = common(arr1, arr2)` etc

Comment: You don't have to explicitly type the arguments in javascript, you can pass any number of arguments to a function, and catch them with `arguments`